# How to add custom text in custom option in magento 2.3.2

Tags: frontend, magento2.3.2, option

How to add custom text in particular custom option after in magento 2.3.2

Comment: can you please elaborate it? I need more details.

Answer (score 0):

**How to Add a new Custom Option Text Field in Magento 2 follow this link**
[1]: https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/how-to-add-a-new-custom-option-text-field-in-magento-2.html